# Chrome: Scaling image makes it break the overflow of outer div while increasing

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I do have a wrapper for image that supposed to hide the overflow of the image when it's been hovered. I did test it in Firefox and Opera where it works fine, but in Chrome it looks a bit strange.

I've made a 10s screen cast to show the current behavior.

Link is https://vid.me/sx0h

Also I did tested in **[JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/0tqjqe9u/6/)** where it actually works fine:

**CSS Code:**

```
.carousel-cell {
  padding: 40px;
}

.carousel img {
  display: block;
  height: calc((100vh / 1.6) - 34px);
}

.carousel {
  margin-top: calc((100vh / 1.6) - (50vh - 57px));
}

.portfolioHover {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolioHover img {
  -webkit-transition : 20s ease;
  -moz-transition : 20s ease;
  -ms-transition : 20s ease;
  transition: 20s ease;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.carousel-cell {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-cell:hover .portfolioHover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: So, if your fiddle "works fine", then what / how are we supposed to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser is probably zoomed in in Chrome, that's why it works in Fiddle. You can zoom the Fiddle to see it breaking. Try `Ctrl +` or `Ctrl -` to get it back to 100%.